# Is there any way for hooking LINQ stored procedure executions?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

Here's the scenario:
Under certain conditions, I want to prohibit ALL database modifications, so I want to prevent the user from executing update or delete or insert statements via a LINQ DataContext.
By overriding the SubmitChanges() method, I can catch any DML-s and prevent them, EXCEPT stored procs.
Of course I know that the LINQ DataContext does not know about the internals of a stored proc, therefore cannot fire an event upon DML statements, but is there any way to get notified that a stored procedure is about to execute, and prevent the execution?

Comment: what do you mean by "user"? how would a user be "executing" SubmitChanges() unless you wrote code that lets them do it?

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is permissions settings.

Comment: Of course it is not the user who calls the submitchanges method :) But there's a lot a code which uses the DataContext, and don't want to mess up the entire codebase, I want a central place in which I can prohibit ANY DML statements-s.
What are these permission settings?

Comment: If you want to prohibit access to certain methods in the datacontext, hide it behind another class that only makes certain functions available, and then use that class as the standard for your data access. Basically, a Repository pattern.

Comment: DLeh, I also thought so, but this would still result in a lot a modifications across the codebase, since I had to replace the old DataContext with the new one everywhere.

Comment: There's probably a lot of places where the code base is making changes too, and you'd have to correct all of those either way. If you do it right, you should be able to conceive a find and replace throughout your codebase to replace the old data access with a new one. You'd have to give a lot more information about the problem to get a real answer, because I don't believe there's any way to modify the submitchanges without writing your own repository.

Comment: Ok, to be clear: actually I already have my own DataContext class, and I can override the SubmitChanges. The problem is: I cannot detect when Stored Procs are called via the DataContext.

Comment: Update your question with some code samples of how SubmitChanges is normally called and how procs are called. That might provide some insight to how we can move forward.